# Toggle div within a list and hide others

Tags: jquery

What I need this to do is toggle .information when .info is clicked, at same time this hides all other .information divs. I can currently do this my problem is when i click to close an open .information div it won't close. How can this following code be amended to do this? I have a toggle() so thought that it would work? Just grasping jQuery!!

```
<ol id="resonsToCome">
    <li>
        <p>A packed and extensive activites programe</p>
        <div class="info">
            <img src="images/icons/information.png" width="24" height="24" />
        </div>
        <div class="information">
            <p>The 40+ activities range from 1 to 2 hours. As everything is on site there is no time wasted travelling which ensures up to 5/6 activities per day.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Instructors stay with their group throughout your stay</p>
        <div class="info">
            <img src="images/icons/information.png" width="24" height="24" />
        </div>
        <div class="information">
            <p>Building a trust and friendship with our customers makes your stay memorable in so many ways.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Friendly and experienced instructors</p>
        <div class="info">
            <img src="images/icons/information.png" width="24" height="24" />
        </div>
        <div class="information">
            <p>Our instructors take part in a rigorous selection and continuous training programme.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>A great environment and perfect location!</p>
        <div class="info">
            <img src="images/icons/information.png" width="24" height="24" />
        </div>
        <div class="information">
            <p>25 acres of beautiful Somerset fields, woodlands and river only 2 hours from London and 1 hour south of Bristol and Bath.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

And the jQuery

```
$('div.info').on('click', function() {
        $('.information').hide();
        $(this).closest('ol#resonsToCome li').find('.information').toggle();
    });
```

Comment: A reson is the sub-atomic elementary particle of logic. Its binary opposite is the Republicon. Currently theoretical, but researchers believe they are close to verifying both and validating their Grand Unification Theory of Politics.

Comment: What about css? If any, please list here.

Comment: Only css to note is that there is a display:none on the div.information

Comment: @Rob - i posted a solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being that you are hiding everything the toggle is just going to re-show the item that you want to be hidden. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.info').on('click', function() {
        var closestIsVisible = $(this).closest('ol#resonsToCome li').find('.information').is(":visible");
        $('.information').hide();
        if(!closestIsVisible)
        {
            $(this).closest('ol#resonsToCome li').find('.information').toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$("div.info").on("click", function() {
    var el = $(this).siblings(".information");
    $("#resonsToCome .information").not(el.show()).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve the problem. That toggles the divs but I still can't toggle the same div (so that all divs are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

See this :

```
$('div.info').click(function(e) {
   $(this).parent().find('.information').toggle();
});
```

This will work. Working fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/RCefe/1/

Click on 1,2,3,4 as they are the text in div with class "info", as the image is not visible. Hope this helps.